# Memory stream namespace and classes can be used in a web app c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memorystream

I'm trying to play a local encrypted video from  a Web App build in C#. 
I'm running a local server in IIS and for getting the video I make a request to this local server. I've searched on Google an Stack and the solution I've seen are using Memory Stream and decoding byte by byte.

Now can this be done in another way for example getting the encrypted video and play while decrypting from Web App ?

Thank you

Comment: A MemoryStream *is* a Stream. You can also get a Stream from a web request. As long as the consumer of the Stream doesn't attempt to set the stream position, (network streams tend to be non-seekable) then you should be able to substitute one kind of stream for the other.

Comment: So in this case if I get this Stream which is a video in bytes, Can i play this video on Web browser ?